# How to add a functionality to stop copy paste on an input field in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm making a form that includes two fields, Email and Re-Enter Email. I don't want the user to copy and paste the email id in the second field. I have to prevent right clicks on the re-enter field and/or the pasting functionality in that field. How do I achieve this? We have onPaste for ui input fields but not for lightning.

Comment: Please don't do this. [This is bad UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21062/preventing-a-user-from-pasting-from-the-clipboard-into-a-mandatory-form-field). It's bad enough if a field has to be entered twice. At least let your users paste content.

Comment: "Please confirm this question by retyping it a second time without copy-pasting." Your users hate retyping as much as you do.

Comment: Also note that people could still enter the email in the second field, and copy it to paste it in the first one

Comment: I wouldn't even keep that field in my form if it was up to me. I fought against it. But that's what I've been 'instructed' to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use HTML event attribute, example-

Component:

```
<lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter some text"  
    oncontextmenu="{! c.handleContext }" onpaste="{! c.handlePaste }"/>
```

Controller.js:

```
handlePaste: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert("yo");
    event.preventDefault(); 
},

handleContext: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('test');
    event.preventDefault(); 
}
```